# Change behavior of FROM_UNIXTIME(0)

Tags: mysql, time, prepared-statement, unix-timestamp

In our project there are a lot of prepared statements which set some values to `timestamp` columns using `FROM_UNIXTIME(?)`. There are several places where logic depends on assumption that `FROM_UNIXTIME(0)` will write `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. And this works perfectly on testing machine.

On another machine mysql is configured to have sql_mode `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`. When I try `FROM_UNIXTIME(0)` there it returns

```
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '1970-01-01 02:00:00' for column 'date' at row 1
```

Unfortunatelly, I can not change neither prepared statements nor mysql configuration. Is there any way to bypass these checks and to make the function work as it works on first machine? I see only one way - by using `IF` statement, but I'm sure there should be something more correct.

Here is a short sscce:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 );
SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
INSERT INTO test VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(0));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [The `DATE`, `DATETIME`, and `TIMESTAMP` Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html):

> `TIMESTAMP` has a range of `'1970-01-01 00:00:01'` UTC to `'2038-01-19 03:14:07'` UTC.
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> Invalid `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP` values are converted to the “zero” value of the appropriate type (`'0000-00-00'` or `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`).

Therefore, `FROM_UNIXTIME(0)`, which is `'1970-01-01 00:00:00'` UTC, is invalid in a `TIMESTAMP` column and will be converted to `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` (if strict mode is disabled).  As documented under [Server SQL Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html):

> If you are not using strict mode (that is, neither [`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables) nor [`STRICT_ALL_TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables) is enabled), MySQL inserts adjusted values for invalid or missing values and produces warnings. In strict mode, you can produce this behavior by using [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html) or [`UPDATE IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html).

Therefore, you can do:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO test VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(0));
```

However, be aware that this will ignore *all* errors (not just an invalid timestamp value).